# Inhomogeneous Diffusion equation on the half-line with Dirichlet boundary Boundary condition (elementary)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

$u_t - k u_{xx} = f(x,t) ; u(0,t) = 0 ; u(x,0) = \phi(x)   \;\;\; x \in (0,\infty)$

I am trying to solve the diffusion equation with Dirichlet condition $u(0,t) = 0$ on the half-line, by the method of extending the domain to $x \in ( -\infty,\infty)$. I know that I can odd-extend the initial data function $\phi$, but I don't know how to extend the function$ f(x,t)$. It seems like $f$ also has to be extended by the odd extension, but I can't figure out why (why not by even extension?).

How should I extend the function $f$?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason _why_ you want to extend the domain to $\mathbb{R}$ and solve and then convert back to the half space?

Comment: @mattos That is how my book (Strauss') solves similar questions to this one!

Comment: I'm pretty sure $f$ would need to be extended in the _same way_ as $\phi$. An even extension of $f$ and an odd extension of $\phi$ wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: @mattos Thank you for your answer. What is the reason that $f$ needs to be extended the same way as $\phi$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, x is defined in half line. Since we know how to solve it in the whole line, we can extend the problem into whole line and solve it. $f(x,t)$ is the function depends on x. Therefore, $f(x,t)$ and $\phi (x)$ have to extend into same way.

\begin{cases}
f(x,t), \hspace{0.3cm} x > 0  
\\-f(-x,t), \hspace{0.3cm} x < 0
\end{cases}